# Mixing Node and AngularJS

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

I am new to the angular world and have an app that has both Node and Angular.

I am at a point where I need to implement some of the node functionality within the angular part.

The node code handles logging and this angular part handles printing of a page to excel. I want to be able to log that the user kicked off the print.
Here is a sample of the node code:

```
const mung = require('express-mung');
var express = require('express');

module.exports = function(apper) {
  function audit(body, req, res) {
    let status = res.statusCode;
    let identity = 'thisapp';
    auditItems(res, status, identity, body);
  }
  function auditItems(res, status, identity, body) {
    try {
       let method = res.locals.method;
       let action = 'log';
       let items = buildItems(res,body);
       let payload = apper.events.items.build(action, items, opts);
       //sends the info to the auditing app
       apper.events.items.send(payload).then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);
    }  catch(e) {
       handleError(e);
    }
  }
  return mung.json(audit, {mungError:true});
}
```

Here is the angular:

```
angular.module('App.Reports').register('MyCtrl'.['$scope', 'LocalService', 'LocalReportService', function($scope, LocalService, ReportService) {
   $scope.export = function() {
       var csvContent= "Building, Grounds, Year1, Year2";
       var dataString = "";

       ReportService.getCsvExport(csvContent);
   };
 }
```

Here is the html where that `export` is kicked off:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <button type="button" class=" btn btn-primary" ng-click="export()">Export</button>
</div>
```

I initially kick off the node component in my server.js:

```
const auditlocal =  require('./lib/my_audit');
app.use(auditlocal(apper));
```

This allows it to work in other parts of the app where only node is used.

Here is the ultimate call to that send:

```
module.exports = function(connection) {
   async function send(payload) {
      return await connection.call('/sessions', 'POST', payload);
   }
}
```

Is there a way to kick off the node audit from within the angular.module?  Or maybe I just have the re-write the whole thing in the angular module?

Comment: are you making a request to an endpoint that is running the audit?

Comment: correct... it is a 3rd party service that manages the audit. When I call send it calls that utility

Comment: What is it you're trying to replicate in angular? Maybe you could clarify that in your question? Is it the `apper.events.items.send(payload)` call?

Comment: correct... that is the ultimate call. I have updated the question with that call. does that help?